# How to reduce space after the end of a tabbing environment

Tags: spacing, tabbing

In my resume, for each of my jobs I have a tabbing environment set up for the name of the company, the city, and the dates for the job. I then would like to have the description of the job immediately following. The problem is LaTeX is adding a big space after my `\end{tabbing}`. I have been working around the problem using negative `vspace` commands, but this is sloppy and I'm sure there must be a better way to do it. Any ideas?

e.g.

```
\newcommand{\job}[6] {
  \begin{tabbing}\hspace{2.3in}\= \hspace{2in}\= \kill 
  {\bf #1}\>#2\> #3 -- #4 \\ %Company  City  BeginDate -- EndDate 
  {\bf #5: }\end{tabbing} %Position:
  \vspace{-20pt} %there is a bunch of space added by \end{tabbing}
  #6 %job description
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the space that is put before and after a tabbing environment is `\topsep`. (And `\partopsep` is added when the tabbing environment begins a paragraph.) So depending on your document you could try:

```
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
```

But be warned that if you change that globally it'll change other environments too. (Itemize, etc.) So you could make the definitions local, or just use `\topsep` as the value for your negative \vspace at the end there.

Comment: Making the definitions of `topsep` and `partopsep` local will also reduce the space before the `tabbing` environment.