# Removing vertical space before and after tabbing environment

Tags: spacing, environments, tabbing

When I write

```
  \begin{tabbing}
  \hspace{4in}\= \kill % set up two tab positions
    {\bf University }, {\it City, NW} \> PhD,
    Physics (2007-2011)\\
  \end{tabbing}
  Methodology and numerical implementation (C++) of methods for
  difficult systems\LaTeX creates a lot of vertical space. I don't want to use `\vspace{-Xin}` to decrease it. It's not accurate. One workaround I found is this:

\begin{ncolumn}{2} 
  {\bf University }, {\it City, NW} & 
  \hspace{1in} PhD, Physics (2007-2011)\\
\end{ncolumn}
  Methodology and numerical implementation (C++) of methods for
  difficult systems\Isn't there a cleaner way to do this using `tabbing`?
```

This solution [How to reduce space after the end of a tabbing environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/how-to-reduce-space-after-the-end-of-a-tabbing-environment) didn't help. I use `res.cls` from http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/

Comment: Remove the last `\\\` after ` Physics (2007-2011)\`

Comment: Please don't use `\bf` and `\it` with LaTeX2e. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it).

Comment: @Danie it removed the extra line but didn't help much. there is still a lot of vspace

Comment: You can use negative `\vspace` to compensate the tabbing. You could use `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` for example to remove a line height.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `tabbing` environment adds `\topsep` spacing above and below it, and also `\partopsep`. Define your environment, for example

```
\newenvironment{nstabbing}
  {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
   \tabbing}
  {\endtabbing}
...
\begin{document}
...
Some text above
\begin{nstabbing}
  \hspace{4in}\= \kill % set up two tab positions
  \textbf{University}, \textit{City, NW} \> PhD, Physics (2007-2011)
\end{nstabbing}
Methodology and numerical implementation (C++) of methods for
difficult systems
```

The two parameters will be changed only inside the `nstabbing` environment; one of course assumes that no list environment will be inside the tabbing.

If the class or the document uses a non zero `\parskip` (additional white space between paragraphs, the environment's definition might be

```
\newenvironment{nstabbing}
  {\setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
   \tabbing}
  {\endtabbing}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. but for some reason it didn't work with res.cls. must be some parameters in res.cls file

Comment: The res class uses a non zero `\parskip` and a `tabbing` environment starts a paragraph. You may trick it by saying `\setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}` in the definition of `nstabbing`.

Comment: @egreg My preamble is <br/>
`\newenvironment{bidding}
{\begin{tabbing}
xxxxxxxxxxx\= xxxxxxxxxxx\= xxxxxxxxxxx\= xxxxxxxxxxx \kill
\textsc{\textbf {West}}  \>\textsc{\textbf {North}}  \>\textsc{\textbf {East}}   \>\textsc{\textbf {South}} \\
}{\end{tabbing} }%end bidding
%`

How (where) do I “insert” your answer into that?

Comment: @blackened I used `\tabbing` where you have `\begin{tabbing}`, so the two `\setlength` command should go before `\begin{tabbing}`.