# Displaying HTML, Asian fonts, fonttype and tabs

Tags: fonts, spacing

How do I get LaTeX to just print the following lines as plain text? The angled brackets are messed up when I compile the `.tex` file into `.ps`

```
the main texts are bounded by <p>...</p> within the <div class = paragraph section> ...</div> attributes
```

How do I change fonts for a single line in LaTeX? E.g. I want the 2nd line to be in Courier New font but the 1st line to be in the normal default font.

```
Httrack  was used for data collection.
**Only raw HTML were downloaded without embedded media files.**
```

How do I enable Vietnamese and Chinese fonts in LaTeX? I want to display the following lines in LaTeX:

```
乌节路 wujielu “Orchard road” was wrongly segmented as 乌 节路 wu jielu “black joint-road”

‘quốc tế’ mean international, but seperating them by whitespaces could have caused a mis-tokenization
```

How do I get a tab in a line in LaTeX? E.g.

```
this    is  a   tabulated   line
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please edit your post to and reduce it to one single question. You may post the others as new questions. All your problems can be solved but it’s better to have them in separated questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Listings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
   \lstset{%
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      language=HTML,
   }
   \lstMakeShortInline|

\begin{document}
   Normal Text |<p>| normal text
   \begin{lstlisting}
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>Hello HTML</title>
         </head>
         <body>
           <p>Hello World!</p>
         </body>
       </html>
   \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

See the package documentation for more information, e.g. automatic syntax highlighting.

### Vietnamese/Chinese

I guess `XeLaTeX` or `LuaTeX` can help. Both are able to process Unicode. All you need is a font containing the vietnamese/chinese characters.

### Tabs

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tabbing}
      Text \= Text \= Text\kill
      a \> b \> c \\
      ddd\> ee \> f \\
   \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

See your preferred LaTeX book/manual for mor information

Comment: Tobi, I realized that when i use {tabbing}, it leaves a large space before it begins the next line. Anyway to resolve that?

Comment: @2er0: See “[Removing vertical space before and after tabbing environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/removing-vertical-space-before-and-after-tabbing-environment)” …

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can also use the `verbatim` environment and the `fancyvrb` package.

```
\begin{verbatim}[options]
  your text
\end{verbatim}
```

and "your text" will be typeset exactly as you have typed it in your `.tex` file and the options can be used to declare fonts. some of the options are `fontseries`, `fontshape`, `fontsize`, etc...

Check the package info for `fancyvrb` for all of the available options.

As for your font type:

```
{\fontfamily{fontname}
\fontsize{fontsize}{CAPSsize}\selectfont{your text}
}
```

Just enter your "fontname", the two sizes (just numbers, no units) and put the text your want to alter in the braces of `\selectfont`.

Comment: `\selectfont` doesn’T have an Argument. Your braces don’t have an effect for this. The magic braces in this case are the one before `\fontfamily` and the last on. YOu should also mention that `\fontfamily` requires the LaTeX (short) name of a font. The first size of `\fontsize` is (nearly) the capital letter height and the second one the line height!