# Adding tabs or creating my own command

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have a problem adding tabs and I can't use a `tabular` environments (like `tabular` or `tabbing`) because I can't mix it with enumerate environments.

Is there a way to add a simgle tab like in any text editor?
I use MathType to make equations writing much easier and there you can insert tabs, so when you export the code you see MathType uses `&` for that, but when you compile that code, LaTeX complains with:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

So somehow LaTeX knows that I'm trying to add a tab and it's driving me crazy.

I thought to create my own "tab" macro or command: the idea is to tell LaTeX to go back to the left (or right) margin with `\hspace` and the move to the "tab" with another `\hspace`, something like:

```
Hi everybody. \hspace{-len_to_left_margin} \hspace{tab_value} My name is Agustin.
```

Is that posible?

Comment: you can not do what you want with spaces (or not without great difficulty) as word space is not fixed so you would have to arrange for your negative hspace to stretch and shrink by the same amount, which is highly variable as tex optimises white space stretching and line breaking over the while paragraph. Your editor is inserting `&` so is expecting the expressions to be in tabular or align or similar environments.

Comment: And is there a way to tell LaTeX to move to a certain position inside the line? Something like: "\moveto{5cm}"

Comment: @Agustin There is a similar question [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051)

Comment: you can go blank line to start a paragraph and \noindent\hspace*{5cm} but really this is all wrong you shouldn't be doing this. Only in very rare exceptional cases should you ever see explicit spacing commands in a document, it goes against the whole point of latex.

Comment: Why can't you use `tabbing`? Can you add some code to your question showing the problems you have using `tabbing`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \itab{Format:}  \tab{$math$ formula}
      \tab{is} \tab{(the real number)}
\item \itab{Example:} \tab{$\pi$} 
      \tab{is (first digits)} \tab{3.141593}    
\item \itab{Ome more:} \tab{$log_{10}(\pi)$} 
      \tab{is} \tab{1.14473}    
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

A simpler approach is put the text in a `\makebox` so we need only one command. In the example, when the text is wider than 25% of the line width,  the text turns red (for demostration purposes) and the length of the `\makebox` is doubled automatically:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,xcolor}
\newlength{\tabcont}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{%
\settowidth{\tabcont}{#1}%
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\tabcont < .25\linewidth}}%
{\makebox[.25\linewidth][l]{#1}\ignorespaces}%
{\makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{\color{red} #1}\ignorespaces}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \tab{Format:} 
      \tab{$math$ formula}
      \tab{is} 
      \tab{(the real number)}

\item \tab{Example:} 
      \tab{$\pi$} 
      \tab{is (first digits)}
      \tab{3.141593}    

\item \tab{Example:} 
      \tab{$\pi$} 
      \tab{is (more digits)}
      \tab{3.141592653589793238}    

\item \tab{One more example:} 
      \tab{$log_{10}(\pi)$} 
      \tab{is}
      \tab{1.14473}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

But there is no need to reinvent the wheel! It could be worth look the [tabto](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabto-ltx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\NumTabs{6}
\item Format: 
      \tab{$math$ formula}
      \tab{is} 
      \tab{(the real number)}
\item Example: 
      \tab{$\pi$} 
      \tab{is (first digits)}
      \tab{3.141593}    
\item Example: 
      \tab{$\pi$} 
      \tab{is (more digits)}
      \tab{3.141592653589793238}    
\item One more example: 
      \tab{$log_{10}(\pi)$} 
      \tab{is}
      \tab{1.14473}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above (without color).

Comment: Really nice, thank. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I've used this for a way of adding nice indentation to itemized lists using [custom bullet] formats. Thanks

Comment: I used this, and when placing a \footnote inside a tab{} it appears the symbol but not the footnote itself, why?.

Comment: @Hans Because is not a good idea include a footnote inside `\rlap` or `\makebox` (try `\makebox{test\footnote{test}}`).  However, note that the last solution with `tabto` package have not this problem.

Comment: @Fran Thanks so much, I "patched" it with a `\phantom` statement, but thanks again, I wanted an explanation on why it didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option that mimics [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764) in [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
% \zsaveposx is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}
\newcommand*{\tab}[2]{% \tab{<len>}{<stuff>}
  \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt}%
  \zref@refused{\thehposcnt}%
  \kern\dimexpr-\zposx{\thehposcnt}sp+1in+\oddsidemargin\relax%
  \rlap{\kern#1\relax#2}%
  \kern\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin+\zposx{\thehposcnt}sp\relax%
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\makebox[5em][l]{\texttt{5em}\hrulefill}\par
\makebox[25ex][l]{\texttt{25ex}\hrulefill} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\texttt{\string\linewidth}\hrulefill} \par
Text1 \tab{5em}{Text2} \tab{25ex}{Text3} \tab{\linewidth}{Text4}

\end{document}
```

It allows you to specify a tab position relative to the left margin of the text block using `\tab{<len>}{<stuff>}`. Positioning is managed via [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to mark the PDF location/length (in `s`caled `p`oints) and then perform the horizontal jumping around via `\kern`ing.

In the image provided, the horizontal tab stops are identified via markers to accentuate the positioning.