# Tabbing from the beginning of a line

Tags: tabbing

I want to tab a list of items like in Microsoft Word, where the tab command always tabs by a fixed number of spaces from the beginning of the line.

Here's a sample of what I'm looking for:

```
Kav       average kinetic energy
N         number of atoms
gamma     a Greek letter
```

What command might I use to obtain the above output?

Comment: Perhaps this `\qquad` ?

Comment: Well,    \qquad does not align the second column properly.

Comment: `tab` is a fixed space, therefore `\qquad` does similar thing. For the exact output, of course extra work need to be done.

Comment: I am looking for something that does 'fixed space' tabbing.

Comment: Latex doesn't work like Word in the sense that you need to tell the computer what exactly the output should be.

Answer (score 11):

## Environment `tabbing`

LaTeX also knows a `tabbing` environment:

`\=` sets a tabulator, which can be again reached by `\>`. `\kill` cancels the line, but keeps the tabulator settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabbing}
    gamma\quad\= a Greek letter\kill
    Kav       \> average kinetic energy\\
    N         \> number of atoms\\
    gamma     \> a Greek letter
  \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabbing]

## Environment `tabular`

A `tabular` can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    Kav   & average kinetic energy\\
    N     & number of atoms\\
    gamma & a Greek letter\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabular]

## Environment `description`

Such a list can also be set as `description` list, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries gamma}]
    \item[Kav]   average kinetic energy
    \item[N]     number of atoms
    \item[gamma] a Greek letter
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result description]

Answer (score 3):

Use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.1\linewidth}p{\dimexpr0.9\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
    kav & Average kinetic energy \\
    N & Number of atoms \\
    Gamma & A greek letter
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[align=left,itemindent=2cm,labelwidth=2cm,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item[kav]  Average kinetic energy
    \item[N]  Number of atoms
    \item[Gamma]  A greek letter
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One more friendly option: use the `tabto` package:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{5em}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Kav   \tab{average kinetic energy}\\
N     \tab{number of atoms}\\
gamma \tab{a Greek letter}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) @Fran, I believe this is the answer to the question and wonder how can the other answers get that number of up-votes while none of them actually answers the question. BTW, I encourage you to add a more complex example to show how `tabto` works and perhaps link to the `tabto` [single page documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tabto/tabto-doc.pdf).

Comment: @AboAmmar People vote mostly on new questions, so it is normal collect few votes for a long time in  late answers. There are no much more except `\tabto*{}`  for overprinting and  `\NumTabs{}` that is the same that `\TabPositions{...,....,...}` with equal spaces filling the line. I have an example  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73394/11604) using `\NumTabs{}` (as well as a poor's man approach to make the same without knowing  `tabto`).

Answer (score 1):

This might do the work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Kav \qquad         average kinetic energy \\
N             \qquad  \ \ \  number of atoms \\ 
gamma  \ \                   a Greek letter 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The alignment is not very accurate (e.g., `a Greek letter` is moved to much to the right) and very cumbersome unless a fixed-width font is used.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, you are absolutely right. The answer is far away from being perfect. Just to tell the OP that Latex doesn't work like Word, therefore for an accurate spaced distance, he/her should use `tabular` or what you've stated in your answer.