# custom indent length

Tags: indentation

[image]

---

How can I apply custom length of indent by giving a "precise word length" instead of estimate numbers under trial and error e.g. `x pt` or `x mm`?

Comment: For a single paragraph \settowidth{\hangindent}{\textbf{A Shot Head: }} will work.

Comment: possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263765/tabbing-from-the-beginning-of-a-line

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Using the `\settowidth` approach isn't quite sufficient: If the right-hand edges of the paragraph are justified, the actual head text has to be encased in an `\mbox` in order to "freeze" the widths of any interword spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\settowidth` macro to set the value of the `\hangindent` length parameter to the width of a chosen string.

Note: If you use hanging indentation, and assuming the right-hand edges of the paragraph are justifed, it's necessaryto encase the head element -- "A short head", "A much longer head", etc -- in an `\mbox` in order to keep LaTeX from stretching or shrinking any spaces that may occur in the lead text. Placing the head element in an `\mbox` "freezes" the widths of the interword spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip} % no \parindent, \non-zero parskip

\newcommand\dummytext{This is a long sentence that will extend to the second line. I want the second line indented by the length of the head words.}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\hangindent}{\textbf{A short Head: }}
\mbox{\textbf{A short Head: }}\dummytext

\settowidth{\hangindent}{\textbf{A much longer Head: }}
\mbox{\textbf{A much longer Head: }}\dummytext

\settowidth{\hangindent}{\textbf{Head: }}
\mbox{\textbf{Head: }}\dummytext

\end{document}
```