# How to set tab in Latex while I do not want orders such 1. 2. 3. etc

Tags: spacing

[Adding tabs or creating my own command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73287/adding-tabs-or-creating-my-own-command/73394#73394?newreg=0559886afad6464195a73fbf879b9c5e)
In this link there are three programs each of which is having programs for setting tab but they have numbering.

```
1. Format
2. 
3.
```

Comment: you need a `tabular` environment no?

Comment: I do not want these numbering.

Comment: A `tabular` does not introduce any numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fran's answer to that question the numbering is generated by the `enumerate` environment, so just remove that. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\NumTabs{6}
Format: 
      \tab $math$ formula
      \tab is
      \tab (the real number)

Example: 
      \tab $\pi$
      \tab is (first digits)
      \tab 3.141593

Example: 
      \tab $\pi$
      \tab is (more digits)
      \tab 3.141592653589793238

One more example: 
      \tab $\log_{10}(\pi)$
      \tab is
      \tab 1.14473
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, this one is working