# Tab in latex for writing code

Tags: formatting

How can I make a 'tab' in latex? I searched a lot, I found something useful but .. I must wrote code and I need a tab of different size. Can someone please help me with an answer?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73287/adding-tabs-or-creating-my-own-command

Comment: please make your question more clear

Comment: The question is extremely unclear and the OP hasn't been seen for a week, so I'm voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

For writing code you can use the package listings (Documentation: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf)