# How to put rows parallel to each other?

Tags: multicol

I would like to have the following rows + stars in the following order. It's kinda hard to put it into words, so I will just show you what I want.

[image]

The code I'm using so far does this only for two columns (Line 1, 2, 3, 4 + stars in column 2). I do not know how to add the other columns next to it, it always goes *under* the existing rows, so it's interpreted as *new* rows.

```
\begin{multicols}           
       \item Line 1
       \item Line 2
       \item Line 3
       \item Line 4
       \item[] \Stars{1}
       \item[] \Stars{1}
       \item[] \Stars{2}
       \item[] \Stars{3}
\end{multicols}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of `multicols`, I'd use a 4 column tabular for this.

Comment: Another option is tabto. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73394/11604