# Aligned equations in LaTeX

Tags: equations, line-breaking, align

I have a long equation in LaTeX, which I need to break up into more lines. I've done this, although its not quite what I was looking for. Here is a MWE showing my problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
        \alpha &= 1 &&+ 2     \\
               &    &&- 3 + 4 \\
               &= 4 \\
               &=5-1,
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So there is a long equation broken into 2 lines, followed by 2 short lines. Here is what I desire:

1. There should be an equation label for each equality sign, so 3 in total. At the moment there is only one
2. The "+2" and "-3+4"-parts are aligned right, which distorts the whole equation. I'm not quite sure why it is doing that, I haven't told it explicitly to do so.

Is there a way to correct these errors?

---

EDIT: Original output looks like

[image: Original output]

Comment: I'd want to point to [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/16595) to another question. This would work in this (simple) problem, too: `\SP` after the `1` and `\UP` in front of the `-3`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Instead of `aligned`, I would suggest an `align` environment; `\notag` can be used to suppress the tag for selected lines; the alignment for the second line can be produced with the help of a `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 1 + 2     \\
&\phantom{{}=1}-3 + 4 \notag\\
&= 4 \\
&=5-1,
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the `{}` at the beginning of the `\phantom` command?

Comment: Beautifully engineered ;). Sad, there is no automatic option for line breaking a sub-equation.

Comment: @Bach It makes the `=` become a relationship operator (to get proper spacing) by giving it a LHS (left-hand side).

Answer (score 10):

> 1. There should be an equation label for each equality sign, so 3 in total. At the moment there is only one

By using `equation` and the sub-environment `aligned`, you told it to generate only one equation number for the entire block. To get an equation number for each line, you can use for example the `align` environment. You can suppress equation numbers for any line therein with the `\nonumber` command. Alternatively, you can get vertically centered equation numbers for broken equations by using the `split` sub-environment for these.

Using `split` unfortunately has the problem that you need manual spacing to align the second part of the broken equation as desired, but if you only want it to be indented enough to clearly indicate it's a continuation of the line above, a `\qquad` produces good results.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
        \alpha &= 1 + 2     \\
               & \qquad   - 3 + 4
   \end{split} \\
               &= 4 \\
               &=5-1,
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

produces something that to me looks good.

> 2. The "+2" and "-3+4"-parts are aligned right, which distorts the whole equation. I'm not quite sure why it is doing that, I haven't told it explicitly to do so.

You did. I'm not 100% sure how exactly `align` and `alignment` interpret multiple `&` markers, but as far as I can tell, they cause alternating right- and left-alignment in each column, so your code placed them left-aligned in the rightmost of four columns. You can push them further left by adding some `hspace*` after any of the two parts, but that will not push them further left than the right end of any other second column in the environment.

I recommend `align` and `split`.

---

EDIT: The aforementioned code looks like

[image: output of code example]

Answer (score 4):

I always use the `alignat` environment for that.
I used `\notag` to have no equation number in the first line.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \alpha & = 1 && {} + 2 \notag \\
           &     && {} - 3 + 4    \\
           & = 4 &&               \\
           & = 5 - 1
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: compiled code]

Comment: To me, this doesn't look good at all with the excessive space on line 1.

Comment: @mrf I mimicked the spacing from the questioner's original output. If you want the `+ 2` and the `– 3` spaced like the `– 1`, just use [`align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74822/16595) or [`split`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74820/16595) and `& \hphantom{{} = 1} - 3 + 4` for the second line.

Comment: What is the diff between `\phantom` and `\hphantom`?

Comment: @Marienplatz `\hphantom` only includes a rule with the width of the content to `\hphantom`, `\vphantom` only height + depth. `\phantom` both. In this example, there will be no difference between `\phantom` and `\hphantom` but try with `\frac{1}{2}` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\eqalign#1{\null\,\vcenter{\openup\jot\mathsurround\dimen12
  \ialign{\strut\hfil$\textstyle{##}$&$\textstyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
\begin{document}
$$\def\T{\mskip33mu}
\eqalign{\alpha &= 1 + 2     \cr
                & \T - 3 + 4 \cr
                &= 4         \cr
                &= 5 - 1,       }$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would nice if an output is generated for completeness.