# Straight ladder layout without breqn

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I would like to know how to obtain the Straight ladder layout as defined under 14.2.1 in the [breqn package documentation.](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/breqn/breqn.pdf) with the "normal" amsmath environments.

I tried

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
R &={} &&A + B + C + D
\\
&&&+ E + F
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

but the spacing around "=" should be equal and not like this: [image: Exap]

A second requirement is, that the resulting equation should get one number. The problem is that `equation + split` does not even allow more than one `&` for aligning.

Answer (score 3):

Like one of these, with `aligned`?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
R =A + B & + C + D \\
 & + E + F
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R ={} &\eqmakebox[A]{$ A $} + B + C + D \\
 &\eqmakebox[A]{${}+{}$}E + F
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of `equation` and `alignedat`?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}% <- Two pairs of right-/left-aligned columns
R & = {} & & A + B + C + D \\
  &      & & + E + F
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: alignedat]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the solutions. 
I realized just now, that my question is not exactly a duplicate of, but gets answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78389/alignment-in-multiple-locations-of-a-single-equation-based-on-first-line).

The approach with `\hphantom` is IMHO the cleanest and nicest one and looks exactly as I wanted it to be.

As one can see in the following example that it is now very intuitive to separate different summands in a term from other terms.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    R
  &=
    A + B + C + D
    \\ &\hphantom{{}={}}
    + E + F
    \\ &\hphantom{{}={}}
    + G + H
  \\
  &=
    A + B + C
    \\ &\hphantom{{}={}}
    + D + E
    \\ &\hphantom{{}={}}
    + F + G + H
\end{split}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. This helped me a lot! I noticed that you followed the proposal to launch a Materials Modeling stack exchange, however have not yet "committed" yet. At this point we need all the help we can get, would you mind to help us by committing? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MTRlZjUyNGY3MGY4ZWY5ZWZkZGVlNmY0NzY5ZjEzN2NjMjNlZTIwMjU0MWU0MDRjNjM2YjIxZmUxNGVhMWZlMHGM23pUo7y5cQ0jl0rBbYtJLWEPnIuIsvgjQSnSfyMm0

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plain `split`, just moving the equals sign in the first column:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R ={}
& A + B + C + D
\\
& + E + F
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]