# How to fit long equation in single column?

Tags: math-mode, align

I am writing a two column document. I am trying to fit following equation in one column.

I read following thread and tried to fit my equation to the given solution but it didn't work

[Aligned equations in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74819/aligned-equations-in-latex)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,mathtools,mathdots,bm,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^{(m,n)}_{ITI}&= \left[xxxxx \cdots xxxxx xxxxx  \cdots  \\ 
                        &  \hphantom{{}=1 }  xxxxx \right]^T  \notag\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

```
%-----------error--------------------

! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \hfil \endtempl...
l.68 \end{align*}

%-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example misses desparately a `\begin{document}`

Comment: It's the usual problem: you can't have `\left` in one alignment cell and the matching `\right` in another. Just omit them, they serve no purpose in this case. When larger fences are needed, use `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl` or `\Biggl` for the opening and `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, `\biggr` or `\Biggr` for the closing.

Comment: Well, there is the trick `\right].`, but it's not nice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can break such an equation while keeping alignment points with a code borrowed from `mathtools`. I define a `\rowvect` command that can have as an optional argument `\big`, `\Big`, &c.. The optional argument inserts a pair of `\bigl…\bigr` and the like. It also defines a starred version that inserts a pair of `\left…\right`.

Demoboth  with the classical trick (`\left.`/`\right.`) and the new command, in which I also propose another alignment:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx,amssymb,mathtools,mathdots,bm,fixltx2e}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode‘\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\rowvect[]
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\abs{star}{
\mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#2
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^{(m,n)}_{ITI}&=\!\begin{multlined}[t]\left[xxxxx ⋯ xxxxx xxxxx ⋯ \right. \\
                        \left. xxxxx \right] ^T\end{multlined} \\
\mathbf{x}^{(m,n)}_{ITI}&= \!\begin{multlined}[t]\rowvect[\Big]{xxxxx ⋯ xxxxx xxxxx ⋯ \\[-1.5ex] xxxxx}^T\end{multlined} \\
\mathbf{x}^{(m,n)}_{ITI}&= \rowvect[\Big]{xxxxx ⋯ xxxxx xxxxx ⋯ \\[-1.5ex] & \hphantom{{}=1 } xxxxx}^T\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]