# New line in Latex Equation

Tags: equations

```
  \begin{equation}
    S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}A_i
    S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}B_i
    S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}C_i
    S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{equation}
```

Considering the above code, I am so interested to know that how it is possible to print these 4 equations, one per line, instead of all followed in one single line.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How can I split an equation over two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/5764); [Aligned equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74819/5764)

Comment: Add [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to your preamble - `\usepackage{amsmath}` and use the `align` environment, breaking lines using ``\\``. Alignment of the equal signs are also possible with `&=`.

Comment: @Werner where should I put `&=`? at the end of each line?

Comment: @lonesome: ``\\`` to end each line, and `&=` to replace your existing `=`.

Comment: you might find the user's manual for `amsmath` helpful: `texdoc amsmath`.  it isn't very long.

Comment: I have already done the job

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `amsmath` provides many environments for equations, e.g.:

- `gather` for centering equations by default
- `align`, which allows vertical alignments

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{gather}
  \begin{align}
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Equation number in last line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    \nonumber S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    \nonumber S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    \nonumber S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{gather}
  \begin{align}
    \nonumber S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    \nonumber S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    \nonumber S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result equation number in last line]

### Equation number in the middle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S=\sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result equation number in the middle]

### Addendum: sign function definition with cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \sgn(x) \colonequals
    \begin{cases}
      -1 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
      0  & \text{if } x = 0 \\
      1  & \text{if } x > 0
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result sgn function]

Comment: Understood. but is it possible to print all under one number?

Comment: @lonesome Answer updated with variants for one equation number.

Comment: Lovely. As an extension to this question, how is it possible to print equation with curly brackets, but for one single function? This is very common in Math to face functions which returns a set of constants regarding to a particular range of inputs. To illustrate these type of functions, there are curly brackets which illustrating them. I hope you do understand me.

Comment: @lonesome Curly brackets can be used as `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: @I do know that but the problem is that the Function notation should come right before the curly brackets, then in each line, the condition and the returned value should be listed. Something like this : [Sing function](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/1/2/c12b404a34258107935dde5f88aaf7a3.png)

Comment: @lonesome See environment `cases`.

Comment: Perfect! As an appreciation, here is your answer selected :)

Comment: Outstanding, thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

You also can have several alignment points per line. For one number  for each group, use the nested environments: `gathered, aligned, multlined` (the latter if you load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`). You also can have `subnumbering` (1a, 1b, &c.)  with the `subequations` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i &S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
  \end{align}

  \begin{flalign}
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i &S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i \\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}F_i
  \end{flalign}

  \begin{align*}
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i &S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i \\
    S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}F_i
  \end{align*}

\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
      \begin{aligned}
        S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}A_i &S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}B_i\\
        S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}C_i & S &= \sum_{i=1}^{8}D_i
      \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we center aligned equations?

Comment: If you have one equation per row, they're all aligned. In the last possibility I propose (two equations per row), it is each group oftwo equations which is centred

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    S &=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}A_i,\\
    S&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}B_i,\\
    S&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}C_i,\\
    S&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8}D_i.
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
  \end{gather}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: lovely, where is the placement for label?

Comment: if you want the equation numbers on the right then you can just write `\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}` instead.  If you want an equation number for each line then search this forum for `numcases`.

Comment: no no, you mistook me. What I meant is where to place a caption/label so I can reference it within my article, using `\ref{}`.

Comment: I disagree. If it was possible to put it anywhere, I wouldn't ask it.

Comment: As an extension to this question, how is it possible to print equation with curly brackets, but for one single function? This is very common in Math to face functions which returns a set of constants regarding to a particular range of inputs. To illustrate these type of functions, there are curly brackets which illustrating them. I hope you do understand me. something like [Sing function](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/1/2/c12b404a34258107935dde5f88aaf7a3.png)

Comment: You can write \label{myeq} anywhere between \begin{gather} and \end{gather} and use \ref{myeq} elsewhere in your document.

Comment: right. I had a spelling error so that is why did not work in the first place. :)