# Aligning an equation in Latex

Tags: equations, align

I've the following equation  :

```
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
  \frac{\partial s}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i -(W\cdot x_i+b))^2}{\partial b}\\

   =\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(y_i -W\cdot x_i-b)\cdot(-1))

   =2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-y_i + a \cdot x_i + b )  \stackrel{!}{=} 0} \\

   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i

   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + n \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i
\end{equation}
```

and here how the result looks like :

[image]

I tough that using align would solve the issue here is what I've tried:

```
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
  \begin{align}

  \frac{\partial s}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i -(W\cdot x_i+b))^2}{\partial b}\\

   &=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(y_i -W\cdot x_i-b)\cdot(-1))

   =2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-y_i + a \cdot x_i + b )  \stackrel{!}{=} 0} \\

   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i

   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + n \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i


 \end{align}
\end{equation}
```

There is now change in the result ! 
My question is how to align the equation despite starting a new line ?

Comment: Proper use of alignment characters. You have to add the alignment character `&` in each line. Equations will be aligned relative to the alignment character(s).

Comment: @Huang_d can you write an example because I've aligned  '&' without any change !

Comment: You can't have empty lines inside a display math environment, and you can't have an `align` environment inside an `equation` environment. Both will throw errors.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  is there no way to align them ?

Comment: I didn't say there is no way to align them, I merely pointed out a couple of obvious mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not very clear how you like format your equations ... Like this?

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
    \begin{split}
\frac{\partial s}
     {\partial b} 
    & = \frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i -(W\cdot x_i+b))^2}
                         {\partial b}\\
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(y_i -W\cdot x_i-b)\cdot(-1))
    = 2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-y_i + a \cdot x_i + b )  \stackrel{!}{=} 0    \\
    &   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i  \\
    &   \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i + n \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As related links on the side indicate (such as this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74822/132800 ), alignment characters have to be put on each line. In your case,

```
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s}{\partial b} =& \frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i -(W\cdot x_i+b))^2}{\partial b}\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(y_i -W\cdot x_i-b)\cdot(-1))\\
=&2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-y_i + a \cdot x_i + b )  \stackrel{!}{=} 0} \\
\Longleftrightarrow& a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\\
\Longleftrightarrow& a\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) + n \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i
\end{align}
```

Comment: thanks for helping but ur answer did't change the result