# Sideways text with rule as table label

Tags: tables, xetex, vertical-alignment, rotating

I've been trying to achieve the following vertical sidebar effect in LaTeX for my resume, but turns out it's far more difficult than I thought (created easily in InDesign):

[image: Sidebar]

I've tried everything I could think of — sideways `minipage`s, `parbox`es, `table`s, `multirow`s, and on and on, but nothing's been able to replicate it. I've gotten close, but never managed to get the title flush along the top of the table (not to mention the centered horizontal rule). Any insight on implementing this?

---

For reference, here's my latest attempt at implementing this with a table and `multirow` (requires XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, multirow, rotating, tabularx, xunicode}
\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
    & \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
    & English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
    & Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
    & \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Technologies} \\
    & OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
    & \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\
    \multirow{-9}{*}{\begin{sideways}\Vhrulefill~skills\end{sideways}} &
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

That produces the following output:

[image: Sample]

---

**Update:** Werner's answer is the one I think I'll go with since it fits my needs well; however, I've been trying to get it in a more general form so I can reuse it easily, and I've run into trouble.

I've created a new environment for this, but unfortunately, I can't get the label to align correctly along the top of the body text using the height of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx, xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newlength{\sectionheight}
\newlength{\tablewidth}
\NewEnviron{rsection}[3]{%
  \setlength{\tablewidth}{#2}
  \addtolength{\tablewidth}{-1ex}
  \settoheight{\sectionheight}{\begin{tabularx}{\tablewidth}{l #3}\BODY\end{tabularx}}

  \begin{tabularx}{\tablewidth}{l #3}
    \BODY \\
    \raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}{\smash{\rotatebox{90}{%
      \color{black!33}\rule[.5ex]{\sectionheight}{.4pt}\llap{\colorbox{white}{\color{black!66}#1}}
    }}} &
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{rsection}{education}{0.5\textwidth}{X}
    & \textbf{Binghamton University, State University of New York} \\
    & B.S. — Computer Science · Expected 2016 \\
    & \\
    & Binghamton University Scholars Program \\
    & Binghamton President's Scholars Program
  \end{rsection}
  \begin{rsection}{skills}{0.5\textwidth}{X}
    & \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
    & English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
    & Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML, CSS, SASS, JavaScript, CoffeeScript \\
    & \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Technologies} \\
    & OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
    & \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL}
  \end{rsection}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, `\settoheight{\sectionheight}{\begin{tabularx}{\tablewidth}{l #3}\BODY\end{tabularx}}` doesn't return the right height for the text, so the result looks like this:

[image: Result]

I'm expecting the label to look right, and for the tables to align next to each other. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: The document cannot be compiled using Latex. It requires Luatex or Xelatex.

Comment: @Vivi That's true — I use XeLaTeX. Is that an issue?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue in terms of your question, but when other people try to compile your document they will not be able to unless they use Xelatex or Luatex. I am only saving them the trouble of having to find that out. Sorry, I am not able to help you with your question...

Comment: Awesome first question! I remember having trouble with sideways stuff in tables some time ... don't think I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very manual attempt at obtaining the result. Since the vertical rule + text spans 12 rows of the table (in my example), I draw a `\rule` of length `12\normalbaselineskip`, and then rotate it into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx, xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tabularx,xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
    & \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
    & English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
    & Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
    & \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Technologies} \\
    & OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
    \smash{\rotatebox{90}{%
      \color{black!20}\rule[.5ex]{12\normalbaselineskip}{.4pt}\llap{\colorbox{white}{\color{black!75}skills}}%
      }} & 
      \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides `\rotatebox{<degrees>}{<stuff>}` while [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) allows for changing the text/rule colours. I have foregone [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) since `\smash` removes the vertical height of its argument.

---

It is also possible to use [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to identify the start/end of the `rsection`, and insert a rule accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx, xcolor, environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tabularx,xcolor,environ}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

\makeatletter
% Taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764
% \zsaveposx/y is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposy}{\let\zsaveposy\zsavepos}{}

\newlength{\tablewidth}
\newcounter{@rsection}
\NewEnviron{rsection}[3]{%
  % #1 = label
  % #2 = tabularx width
  % #3 = column specification
  \setlength{\tablewidth}{#2}%
  \stepcounter{@rsection}% Mark labels top/bottom based on rsection counter
  %
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\tablewidth}{l #3}
    \zsaveposy{rsection-top-\the@rsection}% Store top y-position
    \BODY \\[-\normalbaselineskip]% Place content
    \zsaveposy{rsection-bot-\the@rsection}% Store bottom y-position
    \zref@refused{rsection-top-\the@rsection}%
    \zref@refused{rsection-bot-\the@rsection}%
    \smash{\rotatebox{90}{%
      \color{black!33}%
        \rule[.5ex]{\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip+\zposy{rsection-top-\the@rsection}sp-\zposy{rsection-bot-\the@rsection}sp}{.4pt}%
        \llap{\colorbox{white}{\color{black!66}#1}}
    }} &
  \end{tabularx}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{rsection}{education}{0.5\textwidth}{X}
    & \textbf{Binghamton University, State University of New York} \\
    & B.S. — Computer Science · Expected 2016 \\
    & \\
    & Binghamton University Scholars Program \\
    & Binghamton President's Scholars Program
  \end{rsection}%
  \begin{rsection}{skills}{0.5\textwidth}{X}
    & \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
    & English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
    & Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML, CSS, SASS, JavaScript, CoffeeScript \\
    & \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
    & \\
    & \textbf{Technologies} \\
    & OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
   & \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL}
  \end{rsection}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the labels `rsection-bot-\the@rsection` and `rsection-top-\the@rsection` store the y-position (in scaled points/`sp`s) of the table bottom & top, respectively. An appropriate `\dimexpr` calculates the height of the table and inserts the rule (as before) in the first column.

Comment: I like this answer a lot; it's concise and fits my needs. I've been trying to generalize it though, and I've run into trouble. I've updated my question; any chance you could help?

Comment: @ItaiFerber: I'll hopefully be able to tackle this later tonight (at work now).

Comment: Hate to be a bother, but just wondering if you could take a stab at it in your spare time. I'd definitely grant you the correct answer... :)

Comment: @ItaiFerber: I've updated my answer with a [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)-style answer, which should work with `xelatex`. Let me know if this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an automated solution, allowing page breaks (in the case the table spans several pages); all you have to do is to enclose the table using the `tikzborder` environment, providing as mandatory argument the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, tabularx,xunicode}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{bordercntr}
\newcounter{borderpages}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newenvironment{tikzborder}[1]
{%
  \gdef\bordertitle{#1}
  \stepcounter{bordercntr}%
  \tikzmark{start-border}\label{start-border\thebordercntr}%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr} \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      let \p1 = (start-border.south), \p2 = (end-border), \p3 = (current page.center) in%
         ( $ (\x3,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,2pt) $ ) --  ( $ (\x3,\y3) + (-0.55\textwidth,-0.5\textheight-15pt) $ );
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p1 = (start-border.south), \p2 = (current page.center) in%
node[rotate=90,fill=white,anchor=east,font=\color{black!70}\sffamily] at ( $ (\x2,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,2pt) $ ) {\bordertitle};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{borderpages} {\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}-\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}}\theborderpages
    \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
    \fi
  \fi%
}
{\tikzmark{end-border}\label{end-border\thebordercntr}
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{start-border\thebordercntr}=\getpagerefnumber{end-border\thebordercntr}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      let \p1 = (start-border.south), \p2 = (end-border), \p3 = (current page.center) in
      ( $ (\x3,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,2pt) $ ) --  ( $ (\x3,\y2) + (-.55\textwidth,10pt) $ );
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p1 = (start-border.south), \p2 = (current page.center) in%
node[rotate=90,fill=white,anchor=east,font=\color{black!70}\sffamily] at ( $ (\x2,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,2pt) $ ) {\bordertitle};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      let \p1 = (start-border.north), \p2 = (end-border), \p3 = (current page.center) in
      ( $ (\x3,\y3) + (-.55\textwidth,.5\textheight-6pt) $ ) -- ( $ (\x3,\y2) + (-.55\textwidth,20pt) $ );
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\tikzborderpage{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      let \p1 = (current page.center) in
      ( $ (\x1,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,0.5\textheight-15pt) $ ) -- ( $ (\x1,\y1) + (-.55\textwidth,-0.5\textheight) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \addtocounter{borderpages}{-1}%
  \ifnum\value{borderpages}>1
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{\tikzborderpage}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzborder}{skills}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{tikzborder}

\begin{tikzborder}{expertise}
\begin{longtable}{p{.7\textwidth}}
     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\

     \textbf{Spoken Languages} \\
     English, Hebrew (fluent in speaking, reading, and writing) \\
     \\
     \textbf{Programming Languages} \\
     Objective-C, C, Ruby, Java, Python, HTML + CSS/SASS + JavaScript/CoffeeScript \\
     \emph{Familiar with C++, Haskell, PHP} \\
     \\
     \textbf{Technologies} \\
     OS X, iOS, Xcode, Unix/Linux Systems, LaTeX, Shell Scripting, Git, Vim, Jekyll \\
     \emph{Familiar with Windows, Windows Server, MySQL} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{tikzborder}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution because it's automated, but unfortunately, it doesn't align along the text like I need it to. It's a bit overkill for my needs, but I appreciate it!