# How do I get the width of \hfill?

Tags: tex-core

In my LaTeX document, I have a first line with a given spacing obtained using \hfill, then a paragraph, and then a third line in which I would like to use the same spacing as in the first line.

The first line is something like:

```
a\hfill b\hfill c\hfill d
```

How do I use the same spacing between the elements of my third line as what `\hfill` does between the elements of my first line? The following example does not work, but shows the idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
\newlength{\lengthofhfill}
a\hfill b\hfill c\hfill d\setlength{\lengthofhfill}{\widthof{\hfill}}

This is another paragraph.

e\hspace{\lengthofhfill}f\hspace{\lengthofhfill}g
```

I am guessing that there must be a variable that "knows" the length of an `\hfill` somewhere, I just cannot figure out what it is or how to use it.

As a side question: Is there any resource on these kind of low-level problems with TeX? I never know where to look to solve them, beside Google. I'd love to know a place in which I can see for myself roughly how `\hfill` is implemented, for instance, at a level in-between the LaTeX documentation and the source level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no variable where the size used for `\hfill` is used.

Without taking `\parindent` into account, for simplicity, your first example is equivalent to saying

```
\hbox to\hsize{a\hfill b\hfill c\hfill d}
```

TeX measures the “natural width” of the box as if it had been `\hbox{a{}b{}c{}d}`, since the natural width of `\hfill` is zero. Then it computes the difference between the requested size and this natural width and divides the excess equally between the three spaces.

If Plain TeX with the standard settings is used, the width of `\hbox{abcd}` is 20.5556pt, while `\hsize` is 449.19939pt. Thus each space will be 149.73312pt wide. In its internal representation, TeX would have

```
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 149.73312fill
.\tenrm a
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\tenrm b
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\tenrm c
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\tenrm d
```

so the information can be seen, but it's *not* available at the programming level.

So if you have to use the information, you have to compute it with boxes:

```
\newdimen\usedhfill
\setbox0=\hbox{a{}b{}c{}d}
\usedhfill=\hsize
\advance\usedhfill by -\wd0
\divide\usedhfill by 3
```

---

***Note.*** Why `\hbox{a{}b{}c{}d}` and not `\hbox{abcd}`? Because in the latter case kerning between letters would take place, which it doesn't when `\hbox{a\hfill b\hfill c\hfill d}` is built.

Comment: Isn't it available at programming level with `luatex`?

Comment: @cjorssen Probably it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It makes a lot of sense, I don't know why I didn't think of computing the length myself, considering that I had tried a few approaches with `\widthof`.

Comment: I think \hbox{a{}b{}c{}d} is also wrong, it has to be \hbox{a b c d} and then remove the width of the spaces. Reason: ligatures and kerns also show up on word boundaries and would not show up in the first form

Comment: @FrankMittelbach If I say `\font\x=grmn1000 \gr \hbox{a{}s{}d}\bye` I get "αςδ", so boundary ligatures are recognized also in this case.

Comment: @egreg if you say that then you get \gr not defined :-) but other than that I stand corrected - and thinking about it it does make sense that {} is been taken for a word boundary

Answer (score 4):

The key to this exercise is to properly deal with boxes. In the MWE below, I create boxes that match the widths of the corresponding elements in the first line, yet prints something different with some altered alignment. All of this is made possible by means of the command `\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\newcommand{\lalign}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{#2}][l]{#1}}
\newcommand{\ralign}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{#2}][r]{#1}}
\newcommand{\calign}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{#2}][c]{#1}}
\begin{document}

abc \hfill defgh \hfill ij \hfill klmno

% Incorrect alignment
ab \hfill cdef \hfill ghijkl \hfill mno

% Correct alignment (left aligned)
\lalign{ab}{abc} \hfill \lalign{cdef}{defgh} \hfill \lalign{ghijkl}{ij} \hfill \lalign{mno}{klmno}

% Correct alignment (right aligned)
\ralign{ab}{abc} \hfill \ralign{cdef}{defgh} \hfill \ralign{ghijkl}{ij} \hfill \ralign{mno}{klmno}

% Correct alignment (centre aligned)
\calign{ab}{abc} \hfill \calign{cdef}{defgh} \hfill \calign{ghijkl}{ij} \hfill \calign{mno}{klmno}

\end{document}
```

Above, `\lalign{<stuff>}{<first>}` fixes the width of `<stuff>` to that of `<first>`, while also aligning `<stuff>` to the `l`eft side of `<first>`. Similarly, `\ralign` does this with a `r`ight alignment, while `\calign` `c`entres the alignment. The vertical rules were just added for visual clarity.

[`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) provides the means to calculate widths of things through `\widthof{<stuff>}`.

---

Another way of obtaining this is via [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. It allows you to store the x (or y, or both) coordinates of something using a `\label`-`\ref`-type system. The following MWE construction is partially taken from [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764) and adjusted to accommodate for a parameter. `\SP` saves a position in sequence, starting with 1, while `\UP{<num>}` uses a position saved as number `<num>`:

[image]

```
% Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
% \zsaveposx is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}
\newcommand*{\SP}{% set position
  \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt s}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\UP}[1]{% use previous position
  \zsaveposx{hpos#1u}%
  \zref@refused{hpos#1s}%
  \zref@refused{hpos#1u}%
  \kern\zposx{hpos#1s}sp\relax
  \kern-\zposx{hpos#1u}sp\relax
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

abc \hfill \SP{}defgh \hfill \SP{}ij \hfill \SP{}klmno

% Incorrect alignment
ab \hfill cdef \hfill ghijkl \hfill mno

% Correct alignment (left aligned)
ab \UP{1}cdef \UP{2}ghijkl \UP{3}{mno}

\end{document}
```

However, this is much slower, requiring at least 6 compiles the first time so that the references can settle. This is because each adjustment of an element is delayed by a single compile cycle before it settles.

---

There is also [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) which provides a similar functionality via `\tikzmark`, requiring the placement to be done within a `tikzpicture` (thereby handling the placement entirely from a graphical point of view, and also requiring fewer compilations).

Comment: Thank you! I think combining your `calc`-based answer with egreg's will work well for me. I had read a bit about `savepos`, but that would be really slow in my case (in which I have about 30 positions to remember, on a beamer presentation that is already taking a pretty long time to compile). I sometimes use the `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]` trick to place something, but I didn't know about `\tikzmark`, I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `linegoal`. Please note you need two compilation steps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text \rule{\linegoal}{2pt}

Text \the\linegoal

More more text more textText \the\linegoal
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure whether this can be used if the `\hfill`'s are not at the end of the line but "in the middle" of it, but I will try to remember this package: I can think of a few times in which it would have been helpful. Thank you!