# Indentation in verse environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tufte, verse

I have to typeset a bit of verse in which certain lines are indented to approximately the length of the preceding line, as in these lines from *Romeo and Juliet*. [image: R&J screencap]

I tried to use `\phantom`, like so:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
I am Laertes' son, Odysseus.\\
\phantom{I am Laertes' son, Odysseus.} Men hold me\\
formidable for guile in peace and war:\\
this fame has gone abroad to the sky's rim.\\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. Instead I get the result in this picture:[image: odyssey screencap]

What's the best way to fix this? Once upon a time I used `vinphantom`, but that command seems unavailable (or else is available only in `memoir`, which is what I used last time). What's the best solution?

Comment: You need a `\leavevmode` or `\mbox` to "start the line". See (possible duplicate): [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764)

Comment: `\leavevmode` didn't work for some reason, but `\mbox` does. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show a little more about the poem? To see more examples of what that indent means.