# Number a linear program on the left-hand side

Tags: math-mode, numbering

I want to write a linear program which is numbered on the right-hand side, like it normally is, but which also has a number on the left-hand side. It will be more of a label instead of a number because I want it to have the letter (P) or any other kind of label. I already have written some code, only I don't know how to add the (P) label to the left. How can I do this?

This is the code:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{lp:primal}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} &c_{j}x_{j} &\\
\text{subject to}& \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} &a_{ij}x_{j} \geq b_{i}, &i=1 ,..., m,\\
                 &                                    &x_{j} \geq 0, &j=1 ,..., n.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

And this is how it should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to position the left-side label, I've used some [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) magic from [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764), and therefore the solution requires at least two compilations in order for the references to settle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,zref-savepos}
\makeatletter
% Some ideas taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lplabel}{o m}{%
  \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt l}%
  \zref@refused{\thehposcnt l}%
  \zref@refused{hpos0l}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\dimexpr\zposx{\thehposcnt l}sp-\zposx{hpos0l}sp][l]{#2}}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
    {\def\@currentlabel{#2}\ltx@label{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\zsaveposx{hpos0l}}

\begin{document}

Consider the linear program~\ref{lp:primal} give by
\begin{alignat}{2}
                          \text{minimize}   \quad \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j}x_{j}  &           & \quad & \nonumber \\
  \lplabel[lp:primal]{(P)}\text{subject to} \quad \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_{j} & \geq b_i, & \quad & i = 1,\dots,m, \\
                                                                     x_{j} & \geq 0,   & \quad & j = 1,\dots,n.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The above example provides `\lplabel[<label>]{<stuff>}` that prints `<stuff>` against the left text block boundary and can be referenced using `\ref{<label>}` (if the first optional argument is supplied).

---

Here is a toned-down version which sets the LP label to the left of where it's placed by a distance of `2em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\lplabel}{o m}{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#2\hspace*{2em}}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}
    {\def\@currentlabel{#2}\ltx@label{#1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Consider the linear program~\ref{lp:primal} give by
\begin{alignat}{2}
                          \text{minimize}   \quad \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j}x_{j}  &           & \quad & \nonumber \\
  \lplabel[lp:primal]{(P)}\text{subject to} \quad \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_{j} & \geq b_i, & \quad & i = 1,\dots,m, \\
                                                                     x_{j} & \geq 0,   & \quad & j = 1,\dots,n.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

<sub>[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) provided the left/right boundary.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am still trying to figure out some parts of your code, but it is just what I needed and I only need one compilation. Just out of curiosity: can I change the position of the label, for instance to make it closer to the text?

Comment: @Jessy09: If you want it closer to the text then it's easier to just use `\makebox[0pt][r]{(P)\hspace*{<len>}}` where you specify `<len>` (say `50pt` or `2em`...). You can place this just before `\text{subject to}`. It won't work in the same reference-style way, so you'll have to type `(P)` manually in the text, rather than using `\ref{lp:primal}`.

Comment: I understand. Then I will leave it as it is because the referencing is more important. I just wanted to know how it can be done. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Jessy09: I've added an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution needn't two compilations. It is simply `\hbox` / `\vbox` arithmetic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newdimen\prevdp
\def\leftlabel#1{\noalign{\prevdp=\prevdepth
   \kern-\prevdp\nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss\hbox{#1}}\kern\prevdp}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Consider the linear program~(P) given by
\begin{alignat}{2}
     \text{minimize}   \quad \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j}x_{j}  & & \quad & \nonumber \\
     \text{subject to} \quad \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_{j} &\geq b_i, & \quad & i = 1,\dots,m, \\
  \leftlabel{(P)}  
                                                x_{j} &\geq 0,   & \quad & j = 1,\dots,n.
\end{alignat}    
\end{document}
```