# \hphantom in \tabulary produces extra vertical space instead of horizontal

Tags: spacing, indentation, tabulary

Inserting an `\hphantom` to indent a table row works in `tabular`, but in `tabulary` it produces extra vertical space instead.

Since these are left-aligned `L` columns I would expect the space at the left edge to be preserved, while the space on the right is variable. Why does this happen and how could I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newcommand{\sator}{Sator arepo tenet opera rotas}
\newcommand{\tabindent}{\hphantom{em}}

\begin{document}

\section{Tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\sator  & \sator\\
\tabindent\sator & \tabindent\sator\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Tabulary}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LL}
\sator  & \sator\\
\tabindent\sator & \tabindent\sator\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't depend on `tabulary`; it's the same whenever you have `\hphantom` in vertical mode (after a blank line or paragraph or at the start of a `\parbox`).

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see, it is the same if I use `p{}` columns in `tabular`, because each column is a paragraph.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\hphantom` isn't really a documented LaTeX command and it's a good occasion for talking about it.

The problem can be seen also in this simpler document, which shows that `tabulary` is not involved:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sator}{Sator arepo tenet opera rotas}
\newcommand{\tabindent}{\hphantom{em}}

\begin{document}

\sator

\tabindent\sator

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the “blank line”? Because `\hphantom` *doesn't* start a paragraph, because it is essentially equivalent to

```
\hbox{...}
```

where `...` is some space (the implementation is not really this, however).

Solution: use `\leavevmode`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sator}{Sator arepo tenet opera rotas}
\newcommand{\tabindent}{\leavevmode\hphantom{em}}

\begin{document}

\sator

\tabindent\sator

\end{document}
```

[image]

The definition of `\hphantom` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 4137:
\def\hphantom{\v@false\h@true\ph@nt}
```

The macro `\ph@nt` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 4139:
\def\ph@nt{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\mathph@nt
  \else
    \expandafter\makeph@nt
  \fi}
```

Leaving aside the case of math mode, which is irrelevant here, let's see `\makeph@nt`:

```
\def\makeph@nt#1{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}\finph@nt}
```

The argument to `\hphantom` is actually the argument to `\makeph@nt`; a box is set to contain it and `\finph@nt` is called.

```
% latex.ltx, line 4149:
\def\finph@nt{%
  \setbox\tw@\null
  \ifv@ \ht\tw@\ht\z@ \dp\tw@\dp\z@\fi
  \ifh@ \wd\tw@\wd\z@\fi \box\tw@}
```

The dimensions of `\box0` set by `\makeph@nt` are used to change the dimensions of an empty box (depending on the fact whether `\hphantom`, `\vphantom` or `\phantom` is called, some are changed and some aren't). Then TeX issues

```
\box\tw@
```

which delivers the (empty) contents of the box occupying the stated horizontal or vertical space. Such a command never changes the mode TeX's in, so horizontal mode (paragraph building) is not started.

In the case of `tabular`, TeX is in (restricted) horizontal mode, so the problem doesn't appear.

---

These macros are taken literally from `plain.tex`; there's a nice discussion of the matter in the TeXbook: the concept of “phantom” led Knuth to adding `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` to TeX, so `\ifv@` and `\ifh@` are always either `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` and conditionals can be properly nested.