# How to go to the line below, without changing horizontal position?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I would like to start writing in math display mode, and then continue on the next line, from the exact same . Something like this:

```
abc = defg on this line
                       and i continue on the next line
```

This will be used inside `\frac`.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Preferably without using any packages (I'm sure there must be a way to get this done directly in LaTeX)...

If this were in text mode I could save the current horizontal position, then do a `\newline`, and then restore the position, maybe, but it's math mode.

Comment: Related: [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764)

Comment: What do you mean by "This will be used inside `\frac`"?

Comment: I will write `\frac{A}{B}`, and inside `B`, I'll want to skip to the line below.

Comment: Must we tell a user for more than 6 years to show us a MWE? Nevertheless, see, e.g., `multilined` or `gathered` or `aligned` in `mathtools` and `amsmath`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I don't have a MWE, I couldn't even get close to what I need, so I included the output I wanted. The array approach in Werner's answer seems to work for me -- I'll check.

Comment: You have. You have a document with a `\frac` that should be splitted. So you can make a MWE. We do not need a solution, but an example to work with.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly trivial to obtain with just an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt} % May be needed, depending on your requirements
  \begin{array}{ l l }
    abc = defg &       \\
               & hijkl
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes -- of course!  An array will work just fine (I'll check if no problems arise, but I thin it's perfect). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple with  `align` (or `aligned`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  abc = defg\text{ on this line} & \\
                        & \text{and I continue on the next line}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]