# What is the opposite of \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}?

Tags: spacing, environments, vertical-spacing

I am having trouble removing vertical space *above* the declaration `\begin{quotation}`. The issue with the spacing *below* `\end{quotation}`, however, has been resolved using the command `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.

What is the opposite command to the one given? If the command exists, does using both  `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` and it's opposite work against each other?

I have tried other ways to remove the [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/removing-vertical-space-before-and-after-tabbing-environment?rq=1) but I still cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I should also mention that I used ```\raggedbottom``` before inputting the footmisc package.

Comment: I tried ```\raggedtop``` and ```\usepackage[top]{headmisc}``` but neither of these commands even exist.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you have done. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: To me the opposite of `\usepackage[bottom][footmisc} would be `\usepackage[top]{footmisc} which would put footnotes at the **top** of the page, not the **bottom**,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Are you absolutely certain that fixing some spacing issue below `\end{quotation}` was *caused* by adding the instruction `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` to the preamble of your document? Are there any footnotes on the page that contains the `quotation` environment?

The `footmisc` package calls itself "a portmanteau package for customising footnotes in LaTeX". Section 1.8 of the package's user guide says the following about the `bottom` option:

---

[image]

---

In a comment, you mention that `\raggedbottom` is in effect in you document. That's good, because otherwise the `bottom` option wouldn't have much of a chance of placing footnotes at the very bottom of the page.

I suppose that the "opposite" of loading `footmisc` *with* the `bottom` option is simply to load `footmisc` *without* the `bottom` option. And, as you've already discovered, there is no package called `headmisc`. Finally, the opposite of `\raggedbottom` is `\flushbottom`.

Comment: Since you've answer the question, I have accepted your post. My issues has not, however, been resolved. As you have mentioned, ```\usepackage{footmisc}``` did not solve my problem (I was only convinced it had made a difference). I am going to make a separate post, but thank you for your time.

Comment: @user253822 - Thanks. When you write the new query, please provide sufficient information ideally in the form of a compilable test document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` -- for readers to be able to replicate the issue you're experiencing.